# Uncaught TypeError: e is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, netlify

I am currently trying to add favorites to an exercise list with the following code

```
const addFavouriteExercise = (exercise) => {
    const newFavouritesList = [...favourites, exercise];
    setFavourites(newFavouritesList);
    saveToLocalStorage(newFavouritesList);
  };
```

It works locally, but when I deploy to netlify I get the error Uncaught TypeError: e is null, and it won't add it to local storage.

Any ideas?

saveToLocalStorage

```js
const saveToLocalStorage = (items) => {
  localStorage.setItem("favourites", JSON.stringify(items));
};
```

Comment: Showing the implementation of `saveToLocalStorage` would help

Comment: @RonB. thanks for the heads up, just added it

Comment: Is there anything called "e" in your code? Maybe in a catch (e) {...} clause?

Comment: @Iziminza there is nothing in my code that is called "e", that's the part that is most confusing to me

Comment: @Iziminza The worst part is that I can't recreate it locally, so the only way to really test it is to keep rebuilding on netlify

Answer (score 2):

The bug ended up being in a useEffect that I had, where it was attempting to load items from localStorage but set the favourites to an empty object.

Bugs fixed, phew

The new useEffect looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const exerciseFavourites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favourites"));
try {
  let length = exerciseFavourites.length;
  if (length > 0) {
    setFavourites(exerciseFavourites);
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

}, []);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should find where the E is. And try using `saveLocalStorage` first and then `setState` to avoid rerender before setting it to localstorege